# How to convert in matrix for recommendation

Tags: r, matrix

I have to create a matrix for recommendation, on User-Based Collaborative Filtering

I have values in data frame as

```
> df.user.item

  uname      Item
 user1          I1
 user2          I2
 user3          I3
 user2          I4
 user1          I5
 user1          I6
```

I need to change this as a matrix below:

```
        Item
 uname  I1  I2  I3  I4  I5  I6
 user1  1   NA  NA  NA  1   1
 user2  NA  1   NA  1   NA  NA
 user3  NA  NA  1   NA  NA  NA

 OR

        Item
 uname  I1  I2  I3  I4  I5  I6
 user1  1   0   0   0   1   1
 user2  0   1   0   1   0   0
 user3  0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hi. How did my answer below work out for you? If it solved your problem, please consider accepting it. If it did not, please leave a comment or edit your question to indicate to the community that the problem has not yet been solved.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `table`. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
> table(mydf)
       Item
uname   I1 I2 I3 I4 I5 I6
  user1  1  0  0  0  1  1
  user2  0  1  0  1  0  0
  user3  0  0  1  0  0  0
```

If there are possibilities of duplicated "uname" + "Item" combinations and you are just interested in a binary matrix like you've shown, you can change your command to something like `(table(mydf) > 0)*1`

Comment: thanks, @ananda mahto its really to easy, i missed to check this one. one more help require >> require matrix form of this table structure in matrix, without changing its structure.
matrix(table(mydf)) change the structure. I need same structure as in table format. >> (rownames should be uname and colnames should be item in matrix structure)

Comment: @user_az, I don't understand. A `table` is a `matrix`. Try `is.matrix(table(mydf))` and you will see it returns `TRUE`. Are you trying to do something with the output and it's not working?